# Web config redrict when URL has HTTPS

Tags: .net, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

i wan to try redirect site from

```
"https://abcd.net-------------> https://www.abcd.net"
```

i have already redirect

```
"http://abcd.net-------------> http://www.abcd.net"
"http://www.abcd.net-------------> https://www.abcd.net"




<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" negate="true" pattern="^ON$" />
                </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

need to redirect all 
abcd.net
to HTTPS with www

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to add a new url rewrite rule to match the "https://abcd.net" to redirect to the "https://www.abcd.net".

Details, you could refer to below rewrite rule:

```
  <rule name="Redirect https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTPS}"   pattern="^ON$" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="abcd.net" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.abcd.net/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTPS}" negate="true" pattern="^ON$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```